# Place caret before / after image in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, contenteditable

I have a contenteditable div for a chat. I added a function for adding emoji to the text.
When I'm clicking on the emoji in the contenteditable, I want that the caret is placed before or after the image.

```css
.chat-text-box img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.chat-text-box emoji {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-text-box" contenteditable="true">This is a emoji:&nbsp;
  <emoji class="emoji-icon" contenteditable="false" data-emoji="&amp;#x1F605;"><img draggable="false" src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/2/svg/1f605.svg"></emoji>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create that caret with a pseudo-element `::after` when the text-box has `:focus`

More about pseudo-elements [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)

```css
.chat-text-box img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.chat-text-box emoji {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  /* added this so you can use position: absolute on the ::after */
  position: relative;
}

.chat-text-box:focus emoji::after {
  content: '>';
  display: block;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-text-box" contenteditable="true">This is a emoji:&nbsp;
  <emoji class="emoji-icon" contenteditable="false" data-emoji="&amp;#x1F605;"><img draggable="false" src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/2/svg/1f605.svg"></emoji>
</div>
```

Comment: @NeXuS glad i could help :)